# online ide Runtime Error(NZEC) - python 3 on

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to solve this problem:
https://www.codechef.com/problems/PSCD

My code works fine on my computer but shows Runtime Error(NZEC) on online IDE. How to fix it?

```
tt=int(input())
while(tt):
    tt-=1
    s=list(input())
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        if(int(s[i])<5):
            s[i]=str(abs(9-int(s[i])))
    print(int(''.join(s)))
```

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nzec-error-python/) post on GeeksForGeeks.com about the NZEC error message. Pro tip: Google your error messages before posting them on Stack Overflow ;). Also you might want to add which online IDE and if possible share your code in it via a link in addition to posting it, like [so](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0iDTSA)

Comment: i have tried reading that but i cant solve that error the online ide was codechef ide